# How to get last row in json file using reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I have a json file called **myprovision.json**.

How do I dynamically get and alert the last row content in json file below.
In this context, the last row is biscuit and its total 6.

```
[
      { "pid" : 23101, "provision" : "Tea", "total" : 2 },
      { "pid" : 20981, "provision" : "milk", "total" : 2 },
      { "pid" : 33454, "provision" : "Biscuit", "total" : 6 }

    ]
```

**here is the code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>

   </head>
   <body>

<script src="build/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="build/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="build/browser.min.js"></script>
<script src="build/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="app"></div>

<script type="text/babel">
class Application extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
     data:[]
    };

  }

  componentDidMount() {

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "http://localhost/myprovision.json",
      cache: false,
      crossdomain:true,
      success: function(data) {
         this.setState({data: data});

//alert the data of last row of the json file which is biscuit and its to total value
//alert('am the last row:' +provision);
//alert('am total value of the last row:' +total);

       }.bind(this),
       error: function(jqXHR) {
         console.log(jqXHR);
       }.bind(this)
    });

  }

  render() {
    return <div className="container">


      <div className="row">
        <h3>List of records</h3>
        <ul>

          {this.state.data.map((f, i) => 
            <li key={i}>{f.pid} - {f.provision} - {f.total} </li>)}
        </ul>
      </div>
      <p>

      </p>
    </div>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Application />, document.getElementById('app'));


</script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>


   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to parse the incoming request and get the last elemtn

```js
  success: function(data) {
          const parsedJSON = json.parse(data);

         this.setState({data:parsedJSON  });

         const lastRow = parsedJSON[parsedJSON.length -1]

          alert('am the last row:' +lastRow.provision);
          alert('am total value of the last row:' +lastRow.total);

       }.bind(this),
```